Delayed Rendering React Components
I am making a React App using yet-another-react-lightbox library. It's time to load data from MongoDB. The sample source code has sitemap.ts where all data are defined ahead before rendering Components.
import * as React from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

const data = [
  {
    path: "examples",
    title: "Examples",
    children: [
      {
        path: "basic",
        title: "Basic Example",
        Component: React.lazy(() => import("@/examples/BasicExample")),
      },
      {
        path: "playground",
        title: "Playground",
        Component: React.lazy(() => import("@/examples/Playground")),
      },
      {
        path: "custom-slides",
        title: "Custom Slides",
        Component: React.lazy(() => import("@/examples/CustomSlides")),
      },
      {
        path: "gallery",
        title: "Photo Gallery",
        Component: React.lazy(() => import("@/examples/Gallery")),
      },
      {
        path: "carousel",
        title: "Carousel",
        Component: React.lazy(() => import("@/examples/Carousel")),
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "plugins",
    title: "Plugins",
    children: [
      {
        path: "captions",
        title: "Captions",
        Component: React.lazy(() => import("@/examples/CaptionsPlugin")),
      },
      {
        path: "counter",
        title: "Counter",
        Component: React.lazy(() => import("@/examples/CounterPlugin")),
      },
      {
        path: "mywork/holidays01",
        title: "Counter - My Work",
        Component: React.lazy(() => import("@/examples/CounterPluginMyWork")),
      },
      {
        path: "download",
        title: "Download",
        Component: React.lazy(() => import("@/examples/DownloadPlugin")),
      },
      {
        path: "fullscreen",
        title: "Fullscreen",
        Component: React.lazy(() => import("@/examples/FullscreenPlugin")),
      },
      {
        path: "inline",
        title: "Inline",
        Component: React.lazy(() => import("@/examples/InlinePlugin")),
      },
      {
        path: "share",
        title: "Share",
        Component: React.lazy(() => import("@/examples/SharePlugin")),
      },
      {
        path: "slideshow",
        title: "Slideshow",
        Component: React.lazy(() => import("@/examples/SlideshowPlugin")),
      },
      {
        path: "thumbnails",
        title: "Thumbnails",
        Component: React.lazy(() => import("@/examples/ThumbnailsPlugin")),
      },
      {
        path: "video",
        title: "Video",
        Component: React.lazy(() => import("@/examples/VideoPlugin")),
      },
      {
        path: "zoom",
        title: "Zoom",
        Component: React.lazy(() => import("@/examples/ZoomPlugin")),
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "myphotos",
    title: "My Photos",
    children: [] 
    /*[
      {
        id: "66c66363cfcf8eabf1597223",
        path: "album/ao-dai-viet-nam-0",
        title: "Ao Dai Viet Nam",
        //description: "The most beautiful Ao Dai Viet Nam",
        Component: React.lazy(() => import("@/myphotos/AoDaiVietNam"))
      }
    ]*/
  }
];
// The snippet is used to load data from MongoDB
let albums: [];
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/albums')
.then((res) => {
  albums = res.data;
  //console.log("Albums: " + JSON.stringify(albums));
  albums.forEach((d) => {
    data[2]["children"].push({
      id: d['_id']['$oid'],
      path: "album/" + d['path'],
      title: d['title'],
      Component: React.lazy(() => import("@/myphotos/Album"))
    });
  });
}); 

There are another files:
main.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

import App from "@/App";
import theme from "@/styles/theme";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <App />
    </ThemeProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

App.tsx
import * as React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Outlet, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Divider from "@mui/material/Divider";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

import "yet-another-react-lightbox/styles.css";

import { Link, Section, Paragraph } from "@/components";
import sitemap from "@/data/sitemap";
import MyComponent from "@/myphotos/HelloWorld.tsx";

function Layout() {
  return (
    <Container maxWidth="lg" sx={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
      <Box component="header" sx={{ mt: 3, mb: 2 }}>
        <Link variant="h1" href="/">
          Yet Another React Lightbox
        </Link>
      </Box>

      <Divider sx={{ margin: "8px auto" }} />
      <MyComponent />
      <Divider sx={{ margin: "8px auto" }} />
      <Box component="main" sx={{ mb: 3 }}>
        <React.Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
          <Outlet />
        </React.Suspense>
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  console.log(sitemap);
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
          <Route
            index
            element={
              <>
                {sitemap.map(({ path, title, children }) => (
                  <Section
                    key={path}
                    title={title}
                    path={path}
                    items={children}
                  />
                ))}

                <Typography variant="h2" color="primary">
                  Sandbox
                </Typography>

                <Paragraph mt={2}>
                  Are you looking for a sandbox to provide an example or
                  reproduce an issue? Here is a{" "}
                  <a
                    href="https://stackblitz.com/edit/yet-another-react-lightbox-sandbox?file=src%2FApp.tsx"
                    target="_blank"
                    rel="noopener noreferrer"
                  >
                    minimal sandbox
                  </a>
                  .
                </Paragraph>
              </>
            }
          />

          {sitemap.map(({ path, title, children }) => (
            <Route key={path} path={path}>
              <Route
                index
                element={<Section title={title} path={path} items={children} />}
              />

              {children.map(({ path, Component }) => (
                <Route key={path} path={path} element={<Component />} />
              ))}
            </Route>
          ))}
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

Section.tsx
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Paper from "@mui/material/Paper";
import Container from "@mui/material/Container";
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography";

import { Link } from "@/components";

type SectionProps = {
  path: string;
  title: string;
  items: {
    id: string;
    path: string;
    title: string;
  }[];
};

export default function Section({ title, path, items }: SectionProps) {
  return (
    <Container maxWidth="md" sx={{ my: 3 }}>
      <Typography variant="h2" component={Link} href={`/${path}`}>
        {title}
      </Typography>

      <Box
        display="flex"
        flexWrap="wrap"
        justifyContent="center"
        sx={(theme) => ({
          "--tiles-columns": 1,
          "--tiles-padding": 12,
          "--tiles-spacing": 12,
          [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
            "--tiles-columns": 2,
            "--tiles-padding": 12,
            "--tiles-spacing": 12,
          },
          [theme.breakpoints.up("md")]: {
            "--tiles-columns": 3,
            "--tiles-padding": 16,
            "--tiles-spacing": 16,
          },
          gap: "calc(1px * var(--tiles-spacing))",
          mt: 2,
          mb: 3,
        })}
      >
        {items.map((item) => (
          <Paper
            key={item.title}
            variant="outlined"
            component={Link}
            href={`/${path}/${item.path}`}
            sx={{
              width:
                "calc((100% - (var(--tiles-columns) - 1) * var(--tiles-spacing) * 1px) / var(--tiles-columns))",
              padding: "calc(var(--tiles-padding) * 1px)",
              border: "1px solid rgb(229, 234, 242)",
              borderRadius: 3,
              background:
                "linear-gradient(to right top, rgba(235, 245, 255, 0.3) 40%, rgba(243, 246, 249, 0.2) 100%)",
              boxShadow:
                "inset 0 1px 2px rgb(243, 246, 249), 0 1px 2px rgba(229, 234, 242, 0.6)",
              transition:
                "border 150ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms, box-shadow 150ms cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.2, 1) 0ms",
              display: "flex",
              alignItems: "center",
              justifyContent: "center",
              "&:hover": {
                textDecoration: "none",
                border: "1px solid rgb(153, 204, 255)",
                boxShadow: "0 2px 8px rgb(204, 229, 255)",
              },
            }}
          >
            <Typography variant="h3" component="div">
              {item.title}
            </Typography>
          </Paper>
        ))}
      </Box>
    </Container>
  );
}

Album.tsx
import * as React from "react";
// import axios from 'axios';

import Lightbox from "yet-another-react-lightbox";
import Counter from "yet-another-react-lightbox/plugins/counter";

import "yet-another-react-lightbox/plugins/counter.css";

import { LightboxButton, Paragraph, Title } from "@/components";
import aodais from "@/data/aodaivietnam01";

export default function Album() {
  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const pathname = window.location.pathname;
  const path = pathname.substring(pathname.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
  console.log("hit the backend to load dataset for " + path);
  return (
    <>
      <Title>The  Ao Dai Collection</Title>
      <Paragraph>Bo Suu Tap Ao Dai Viet Nam.</Paragraph>
      <Paragraph>{pathname}</Paragraph>

      <Lightbox
        open={open}
        close={() => setOpen(false)}
        slides={aodais}
        plugins={[Counter]}
      />

      <LightboxButton onClick={() => setOpen(true)} />
    </>
  );
}

But I am struggling to render the components defined with MongoDB data. As shown in the screenshot, My Photos has nothing. But if I click on My Photos, the expected components are rendered.

Then go back to the home page, the expected components are indeed rendered late. I guess the issue might likely be relevant to the use of axios - asynchronous call but I have no clue how to fix the issue. Can anyone help?


Try to load axios in useEffect at App.tsx and then map it.

@Minh: thanks! I sorted the issue out by using useEffect in App.tsx to update sitemap variable.
